# Load page with specific background-color on radio button based on database output

Tags: php, html, css

I have a few radio buttons that light up green when page loads. 
However, I'm creating a "order system" of some sort, and when that specific button or "locker" in my example, I want that specific "locker" to be "locked" (light up red instead of green) when page loads.

I already have the basic set up within my database to echo out "Active" or "Inactive" just to make sure it actually works. But I havent been able to actually modify the radio button based on SQL output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you need more information, I'll upadte.

EDIT: 
To give it a more visual look, I want the lockers to be red, if the locker has been ordered.

http://prntscr.com/bji7g0

Comment: paste your code here what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to make a class in you css called Active for your radios that display Green, and Inactive that display Red.
In your html/php just echo the status in the class attribute :

```
<input class="<?php  echo $obj['STATUS']; ?>" type="radio" name="my-name" value="1"> Test<br>
```

Comment: Genius! Give me a moment to try this out

Comment: Quick question..
How to I add a class to my <label for="A1-1">A1-1</label>

Comment: Make the same things for the label class="<?php  echo $obj['STATUS']; ?>" and create a class Active and Inactive

Comment: Oh before the "for".. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i assume your html content looks like this

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_example" value="Active" />
<input type="radio" name="radio_example" value="inactive" />


<?php $value="Active" ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     var x = <?php echo $value; ?>

document.querySelector('[name="radio_example"[value="'+x+'"]').checked = true;

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need this in .php file you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($orders as $o) {
    $content .= '<button class="'.($o['active'] ? 'green' : 'red').'">'.$o['name'].'</button>';
}
```

If you need in html, you can do by get/post queries (for example, with help ajax)